# Why AWS SQS does not provide push mechanism through a long-live connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

AWS SQS provides long polling and short polling, but why it doesn't provide push mechanism, like RabbitMQ?

The application could establish a long-lived connection, and consume the messages, which is pushed from the SQS queue.

Comment: This is exactly how SNS works.  Don't use a hammer as a screwdriver.

Answer (score 3):

This is a design choice and makes sense when considering use cases for which SQS is designed.

1. **Serverless Computing**: SQS is a core service when it comes to designing serverless architectures. In such systems there is no concept of "persistent servers" and hence no need for long lived connections. This is also why the pricing model of SQS is primarily on the API calls.
2. **REST API Access vs Connections**: To me, this speaks everything. When in an serverless environment having REST APIs to the microservices is needed. This is because I cannot program around when the compute node would be provisioned and deprovisioned, eg in lambda there are no hooks for these actions. This means I will either have to introduce a new layer - Connection Pools or live with having dangling connections. If not I will end up opening and closing connections for every single operation (or lambda invocation) which will not give me any benefits of the "connection" in the first place. Here having REST API makes sense. 
   **This is also why DynamoDB (database) is made accessible via a REST API and Aurora now has a serverless alternative, which as you guessed, has REST API.**
3. **Overhead of long-lived connections**: The overhead of long lived connections, on either end is expensive enough and would require a completely different architecture. This again tied down to the above point of not having servers to keep the connections open in the first place.

Disclaimer: This answer comes from my experience of building architecture on AWS.